# Boot SSD reporting Read-Only Status

Tags: windows-10, boot, read-only

My PC suddenly stopped working and it would never boot into windows, getting blocked instead at "Stop Code: Registry Error" BSOD when trying to boot.

Safe Mode not available, can't restore and even reset PC doesn't work.

chkdsk e: does seem to go through but ends with:

> The Volume Bitmap is incorrect.
> Windows has checked the file system and found problems.
> Please run chkdsk /scan to find the problems and queue them for repair.

chkdsk /scan doesn't run:

> A snapshot error occurred while scanning this drive. Run an offline scan and fix.

Similar with

chkdsk E: /f

> Cannot lock current drive.
> Windows cannot run disk checking on this volume because it is write protected.

Reset this PC, as mentioned, did not work:

> There was a problem resetting your PC. No changes were made.

I then tried with:

dism /image:E: /cleanup-image /restorehealth /scratchdir:c:\scratch

But got an error:

> Error 19 - The media is write protected

BCDEdt Output:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=D:
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {default}
resumeobject            {bunchofnumbers}
displayorder            {default}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {default}
device                  partition=E:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 10 
locale                  en-US
recoverysequence        {current}
recoveryenabled         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=E:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {bunchofnumbers}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
```

Continued with DISKPART, specifically the "Attributes disk clear read-only" instruction. Error:

> Diskpart failed to clear disk attributes

I checked the details of the drive through diskpart and got:

> Samsung SSD 980 PRO 2TB
> Status Online
> Current Read-only State: Yes
> Read-only:  No

It has D, E and F on it, D being System Reset and F Hidden.

Apparently there is a registry key that holds Read Only value that can be changed. However this key did not even exist so I assume that can't be it. I still decided to create the value and add it:

> REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies

> REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies /v WriteProtect /t REG_DWORD /d 0

No change and after restart and autrepair, the key is gone anyway.

I copied all the important data from the E boot drive (which is labeled as C in my system) to the other drive in my system, C: (which is labeled as G in my PC but I guess that's not relevant). I can browse through the E: through cmd, but booting will not work and anything that makes any changes to the drive is not allowed. At the moment I don't have an option to test the SSD in another PC.

So... any other things I could try? Or straight to the verdict?

Comment: [Boot] SSD reporting Read-Only Status => drive has reached the end of its life.

Comment: @AndrewMorton In what way? The SSD is 11-12 months old, so it would have to be an extraordinary malfunction? What's the best way to check that, considering its "read-only" state?

Comment: You're stuck unless you can get that drive in another PC or boot another OS on your PC temporarily.  My next steps would be to reset the UEFI to defaults just in case something there is being weird, and then try to read the device's SMART parameters from another OS or PC and see if any of the parameters are way off.  The last ditch thing to do would be to try to update its firmware, and you should copy all important data off the device (using another PC Or OS) before you do that.

Comment: @LawrenceC I have copied all data from the drive and I installed Windows on an old SSD. I ran the Samsung Magician and I don't understand these values.

First of all, it says Drive Health Critical, with all values good (device life still 100%) except Available Spare which is at 0 and that is the one that makes it overall critical. Available Spare Threshold is said to be 10.

Just to clarify - I am still not able to delete anything from the drive (I can copy from it), I can't format it.

Comment: Actually, could it be zero, because it's read only. It would make sense then. You can' write on it, so there is no more spare. The official remaining space is otherwise 70% left.

Comment: @NxT Are you sure that the drive was new when you got it? In the Drive Health panel in Samsung Magician, how many TB does it say have been written? What is the value of Power On Hours in the S.M.A.R.T. statistics (there are 8760 hours in a year)?

Comment: "Available Spare" is space the SSD reserves to replace bad blocks.  0 left means if a block goes bad (wear occurs during writing), you lose data, so fortunately your SSD goes in to read-only mode (some just die).  Your SSD is worn and should not be used any more.  If it's about a year old, and it was billed as new from the vendor, the SMART data you have is evidence that the device is either not new or bad and may help you get a replacement, unless you were writing multiple TBs a day to it or the SSD is very old.

Comment: @AndrewMorton The reported values are interesting.
Critical Warning 9 CRITICAL |
Available Spare 0 CRITICAL |
Available Spare Threshold 10 OK |
Percentage Used 0 OK |
Data Units Read 10954677 OK |
Data Units Written 20340025 OK |
Host Read Commands 162188515 OK |
Host Write Commands 446534473 OK |
Controller Busy Time 2153 OK |
Power Cycles 491 OK |
Power On Hours 0 OK |
Unsafe Shutdowns 0 OK

So that is 9.7TB written. And power  on hours... 0?! Unsafe shutdowns is also higher than zero. I have one per week, some hibernation related problem.

Comment: @LawrenceC Yeah, I'm pretty sure it's new. Reputable vendor, legit packaging. As the data shows, 9.7 TB written, although zero Power on Hours definitely looks suspicious. Your explanation of why it's in read-only mode definitely sounds reasonable.